# HTML5 Canvas Error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

when i try to run this javascript it says that theres an error "INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1"

Javascript:

```
blocksize=50;
ctx=document.getElementById('wizard1').getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('wizard.png'),0,0,105,105,0,0,3/7*blocksize,blocksize);
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id='wizard1'></canvas>
<img id='wizard.png' src='wizard.png' />
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The wizard.png image wasn't 105px wide, so the drawImage was trying to retrieve data that wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `width` and `height` attributes on the canvas element (not CSS, actual attributes in the markup). They're used to establish the coordinate system, so that could be the cause. (Untested, though.)

Comment: canvas defaults to 300x150 so thats not an issue